# Having two activities with Mainctivity causes the back button to not work properly

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I have a MainActivity and I am posting partial code here:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_quit:
        moveTaskToBack(true);
        return true;
    case R.id.action_help:
        //display the help activity
        Intent myIntent = new Intent( this, ShowHelp.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        return true;
    case R.id.action_about:
        //display the about window
        //aboutApp();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
public void aboutApp() {
    // custom dialog
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.about);
    dialog.setTitle("About TollCulator");

    TextView textViewAbout = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvContents);

    textViewAbout.setText("About: ");
    textViewAbout.append("\n\tTollCulator - Toll Calculator");
    textViewAbout.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
    Button btnCloseIt = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnOk);
    // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
    btnCloseIt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    ImageView iv1 = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.imgFB);
    iv1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/PagesByZ");); 
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            dialog.cancel();
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
}
```

ShowHelp.class partial code here which is an Activity on it's own:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case 16908332:
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            //finish();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // do something on back.
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    //finish();
    return;
}
```

Now when i choose `action_help` from the menu it opens the ShowClass Activity and I can press the back button and it brings me back to MainActivity without any problem.

Now If I choose `action_about` the About Dialog pops up and If I click on the icon within the Dialog the following pops up:
[image]

At this time If I decide to press BACK, instead of closing the pop and displaying my About Dialog, I am just taken to the Homescreen.

**Commenting the `finish();` method in ShowClass allows me to click the BACK button from the "Complete action using" But instead of taking me to the MainActivity, it takes me to ShowClass from there I can press the Back button again to come back to MainActivity. So as long as I choose `action_help` first, pressing back brings me back to the ShowHelp.**

When the Complete action using pops up from the About Dialog, I set up a Log, and it's on the onPause() state and if I did not run ShowHelp in the beginning, my App goes directly to onStop() and onDestroy().

Please help me fix the issue.

To test it, I created a demo without the ShowHelp class with just the dialog and By pressing back button, the Complete actiong using dialog closes and then pressing back again closes the About Dialog. So I am not sure what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a global boolean variable `chooserIsShowing`:

```
boolean chooserIsShowing;
```

Set it to true here:

```
ImageView iv1 = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.imgFB);
iv1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // set the flag
        chooserIsShowing = true;

        Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/PagesByZ");); 
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        dialog.cancel();
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Change the overriden `onBackPressed()` method:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if (!chooserIsShowing) {
        // do something on back.
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        finish();
    }

    // remove the flag
    chooserIsShowing = false;
    return;
}
```

**Edit 1:**

Declare `dialog` as a global variable:

```
Dialog dialog;
```

Change `aboutApp()`:

```
public void aboutApp() {

    dialog = new Dialog(this);
    ....

}
```

Override `onKeyDown(int, KeyEvent)` method in MainActivity:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

You can remove `chooserIsShowing` as its not required.

**Final Solution:**

A `noHistory` flag was defined for this activity in the manifest. Removing that and fixing `onBackPressed()` method of `ShowHelp` resolved the issue.

Comment: The only issue is, I will have to use SharedPreference? As they are in two different classes?

Comment: @ZahidH `Now when i choose action_setting from the menu it opens the ShowClass Activity` <<< Do you mean `Now when i choose **action_help** from the menu it opens the ShowClass Activity`?

Comment: @ZahidH Also, do you have the `onBackPressed()` method in MainActivity?

Comment: I am sorry, Yes `action_help`.

Comment: onBackPressed() is only on `ShowHelp` Because it's a different Activity. Maybe I need something like that on my MainActivity?

Comment: I can send you the project file for review :)

Comment: @ZahidH See **Edit 1** above.

Comment: Take out the **`Final`**?

Comment: @ZahidH Yes. It's not required.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35620/discussion-between-vikram-and-zahid-h)

Comment: Thank you... You have been a great HELP! :)